# self.request.user does not work in Django REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to give only the information of the user who requested with `self.request.user`, but for some reason, this way I get the information of all users.

How can I improve this so that we can retrieve only the information of the user who requested it?
Please let me know if you know anything about this.

View

```
class StatisticsViewSet(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = EntrySerializer

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = self.request.user.entries.all()
        serializer = StatisticsSerializer(queryset)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Serializer

```
class StatisticsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    daily_report = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    daily_report_week = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_daily_report(self, obj):
        data = Entry.objects.filter(user=obj.user).values(
            'created_at__year', 'created_at__month',
            'created_at__day').annotate(Sum('time')).order_by(
                'created_at__year', 'created_at__month', 'created_at__day')
    ........
    ...
    ...
```

Model

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project,
                                related_name='entries',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                             related_name='entries',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.project.name, self.created_at)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the queryset inside the serializer using the context

Serializer:

```
class StatisticsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    daily_report = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    daily_report_week = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_daily_report(self, obj):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        data = Entry.objects.filter(user=user).values(
            'created_at__year', 'created_at__month',
            'created_at__day').annotate(Sum('time')).order_by(
                'created_at__year', 'created_at__month', 'created_at__day')
```

View:

class StatisticsViewSet(APIView):
permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
serializer_class = EntrySerializer

```
def get(self, request):
    queryset = self.request.user.entries.all()
    serializer = StatisticsSerializer(queryset, context = {'request': self.request)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried it, but I get the error `KeyError at /api/statistics 'request'`.
Is it possible to use a request without taking a request as an argument in the first place?

Comment: This answer works if you had `GenericAPIView` and not `ApiView`. For this to work with `ApiView` simple change this line in your view class `serializer = StatisticsSerializer(queryset, context={'request': self.request})`